# Missing Faces When Creating iPhoto '11 Smart Album

Tags: photos.app

I am having trouble creating a Smart Album based on Faces in iPhoto '11. Whenever I set up a Smart Album condition using "Face IS" the third drop-down menu is populated with a list of my Faces. This list contains many of the names of faces I have set up, but there are names missing from the list that always appear if I go directly to the Faces corkboard.

Any idea why some of my Faces are missing from this drop-down list?

The other weird thing is that there are several duplicate listings in the drop-down list that I have merged within the Faces corkboard and are now listed as a single person. Is there some way to force the Smart Album list to update?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried rebuilding the photo library?  Launch iPhoto while holding opt+cmd - I will generally select all options except to restore from a backup.